# Delete currentUser in NSMutableArray Parse iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I want to load friends with Parse, but remove currentUser Object, how can I make it ? What am I making wrong ?

I tried with this code, but it doesn't work :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query orderByAscending:@"name"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            self.allUsers = objects;
            self.mutableAllUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.allUsers];
            [self.mutableAllUsers removeObject:self.currentUser];
            [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.mutableAllUsers);
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it :
add     `[query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:self.currentUser.objectId];` in query. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
[query whereKey:@"username" notEqualTo:currentUser.username]
```

That should work :)

Comment: thanks man, but my reply is fine :) e.g : [query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:self.currentUser.objectId];

Comment: You are right, i think objectId is better. but both should work.